# How to deterine why an internet connection is atypically faster or slower?

Tags: networking, router, internet, internet-connection, speed

Sometimes, at single location, when nothing has changed with local hardware or software, internet throughput will be notably faster or slower.

The first step, I have found, is to test on a wired connection (often Ethernet) in order to eliminate the possibility of local WiFi interference.

The second step, is to reboot everything.

The third step, is to ensure the there is no significant traffic on the local device/network.

In the past, one could go to the [Internet Traffic Report](http://internettrafficreport.com/) to check up-to-the-minute regional and global network congestion.  It was an excellent tool.  But the data on that site has not been updated for nearly 2 years, making it useless.

What steps can be taken after to determine the cause of the atypical speed variance after it has been determined that it is not caused by WiFi interference?

Comment: Try speedtest.net and then see if big downloads and/or videos are occurring when you experience a slowdown.

Comment: @John Thanks John.  Yes, speedtest.net (or similar sites) will typically show the atypical speeds, but they offer no reason for it.  I've updated the question to resolve the second part of your suggestion... thanks for pointing out that omission to me.

Comment: If there is little or no local traffic but (according to Speedtest) there are changes in speed, you need to document this and approach your ISP.

Comment: @John When I have approached ISPs, they always claim that everything is working perfectly on their end (unless they are having a major known issue).  So part of my goal is to validate or invalidate such claims.  For example, if the global and regional Internet are light and the local connection is slow, then it possibly invalidates their claim, but if Internet traffic is heavy and the local connection is slow, it's possible the Internet itself is just having a slow day.

Comment: I cannot see you would have speed fluctuations with no load and all well with the ISP.  I hook up a computer directly to the ISP Modem and disconnect my own network when contacting them.

Comment: Hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://www.highspeedinternet.com/resources/why-is-my-internet-so-slow